# How to make big number of holes

Tags: modifiers

I need to make a big number of holes as shown in the [video](https://youtube.com/live/-J1joqFzALY?feature=share) but more efficiently

I also join cylinders but my object is union with them [video](https://youtube.com/live/VIUBpXUpLI4?feature=share). Why sometimes it Difference objects but sometimes Union them? Like in this [video](https://youtube.com/live/PbL0krSZBIM?feature=share)

The picture is here:
[image: picture]

Comment: This seems to be wrong approach. If you have something repeating, you should aim to model it once and repeat it. Array Modifier has Object mode that you can use to rotate array objects around so you can model one segment, and repeat it around easily.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28103/creating-a-truck-exhaust-mesh https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63196/how-to-make-this-cylinder-model-with-holes https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79650/regularly-spaced-holes-in-a-cylinder https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/167717/how-to-make-these-holes-the-same-size

Comment: Hello and welcome. This question seems to have been asked before in multiple forms over time, and already has various answers but you never acknowledged any of them. We are not sure if you aware of the existing posts but none of the described techniques address your particular requisites, or you simply didn't do any research at all. Could you [edit] you post and clarify how your question differs from the suggested duplicates? Otherwise could you rephrase it to focus on a particular step you are stuck with?

Comment: Maybe you can pick and choose from [this modifier stack](https://blend-exchange.com/b/NDR66qNp/)

Answer (score 1):

First, you should probably use the fast solver on boolean modifier.

Second, booleans will act better with a proper amount of supporting edges and it's best if you make sure you don't overlap any edges and create weird geometry.

So as mentioned in the comments your best bet is to model one side of this structure with the windows cut out and then instance it around in a circle.